# I want to find the reason why my soft keyboard will not dismiss

Tags: android, iphone, keyboard

In my android application, I have a dialog in one fragment and this dialog contains a edittext, I use showSoftInput to let soft keyboard showing. But when I tap outside the dialog(not tap the keyboard button or edittext), the dialog should dismiss and it does. The weird thing is when the phone in portrait view the softkeybaord will not dismiss following the dialog but in landscape view the softkeyboard dismiss.

Anyone meets this case? And I find this in the android developer website:Note: Once the input method is visible, you should not programmatically hide it. The system hides the input method when the user finishes the task in the text field or the user can hide it with a system control (such as with the Back button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my root reason, it is because the host activity set:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"`.

After I remove this, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I got one more solution to hide keyboard

`InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);`

Add this on tap outside